# HTML Data Scraping (I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, world-of-warcraft

I am currently doing some work for a client which happens to be a video game group for the game World of Warcraft.

They want to show their current rating on their website.

The ratings are shown [here](http://www.wowprogress.com/guild/us/caelestrasz/Crimson/rating.tier13_25).

They would like to have the number for 'Oceanic', and the number for 'US' displayed on their website.

Is anyone able to show me a way that I can have those numbers automatically update on the website should they change?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to server side scripting, e.g., PHP?

Comment: Yeah, I have access to all files/databases etc.

Comment: You can't do this with jQuery, as it requires sending a request across  domains. You need PHP or a serverside language.

Comment: Would you be able to assist me with that? I have no real knowledge of PHP... Only the basic PHP that wordpress uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this snippet to scrap the data - assuming PHP is okay since you're running wordpress. I'd save these values in a database/flatline/cache.

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.wowprogress.com/guild/us/caelestrasz/Crimson/rating.tier13_25');

$oceanic = explode('<dt>Oceanic: </dt>', $data);
$oceanic = substr($oceanic[1], 4, strpos($oceanic[1], '</dd>') - 4);

$us = explode('<dt>US: </dt>', $data);
$us = substr($us[1], 4, strpos($us[1], '</dd>') - 4);

echo 'Oceanic: ' . $oceanic . "<br />\n";
echo 'US: ' . $us . "<br />\n";
```

Comment: Thankyou so much man, you're awesome :)!

Now I just have to figure out how I can apply a div or something similar to that to allow styling.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy. I prefer using [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), but you can also use the builtin php dom parsing methods.

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.wowprogress.com/guild/us/caelestrasz/Crimson/rating.tier13_25');
$xxx = $html->find('div.guildStats dl dd');

foreach($xxx as $k)
echo $k->plaintext."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to cross domain security you cannot do this with javascript, you will have to get your information server side if you have access to it.

Comment: I have access to my server, or do you mean from their server?

Comment: Nope from your server back end code on your server i belive john has shown a example in php below

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with RegEx.

```
<?php

$data = implode('', file('http://www.wowprogress.com/guild/us/caelestrasz/Crimson/rating.tier13_25'));
$pat_world = '/<span class="rank blue">(\d+)<\/span>/';
$pat_us = '/<dt>US:\D+(\d+)/';

preg_match($pat_world, $data, $world);
preg_match($pat_us, $data, $us);

echo $world[1];
echo "\n\n";
echo $us[1];
```

I know everyone is anti-regex for web scraping, but I think it works just great in simple situations like this.

Comment: I could actually simplify the first pattern, not that it would change the results.  `/<dt>world:\D+(\d+)/` works just the same.

Comment: Using regex can be a pain to debug, especially after 6 months, if they change the layout. I find it easier to debug a string of simple function calls.